# f=sym('f',[1 4]) q=zeros(1,4) for i=0:3 f(1,i+1) = (@(x)(exp(-x).*(x.^0.5).*x.*laguerreL(i,0.5,x))) %g(1,i+1)=quadgk(f(1,i+1),0,1) end

Tags: matlab, integer, double, boundary

what is the problem of this code?

please discribe the problem for me
f=sym('f',[1 4]) q=zeros(1,4) for i=0:3 f(1,i+1) = (@(x)(exp(-x).*(x.^0.5).*x.*laguerreL(i,0.5,x))) %g(1,i+1)=quadgk(f(1,i+1),0,1) end
in this code i want to calculate double int that funtion is a array of M+1 dimention

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] before [edit]ing your question to improve the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and clarify the issue

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the problem is, if you don’t tell us what the code is supposed to do, or what it does.  Also, please don’t put code in the title, write a short title that describes the question. It’s the thing that people must click to see your question, it must entice the people that could answer your question to click it.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure
hold on

q=zeros(1,4);
for k=1:4 
    
    f1=@(x) (exp(-x).*(x.^0.5).*x.*laguerreL(k,x)); 
    fplot(f1);
    g(k)=quadgk(f1,0,1) 
end

grid on
legend('1','2','3','4')
```

[image]

The resulting integrals

```
g'
ans =
   0.067073046736390
  -0.016768261684098
  -0.064107950475923
  -0.085353721623712
```

There are no LaguerreL polynomials of order 0.

In MATLAB the 1st element is always indexed 1, not 0.

Comment: How I can evaluate the integral of "@(x,t)(exp(-x).*(x.^0.5).*x.*laguerreL(k,x)).*exp(-t).*x.^(-0.5).*laguerreL(k,t)"from k=0:3?

Comment: Shiva : 1.- in laguerreL(k,t) k isthe polynomial order and t the variable 2.- f(x,t) can be integrated for 2.1.- volume 2.2.- area, or 2.3.- along a path. What integral do you need?

Comment: asking for integral k [0 3] does not make sense without defining an x t domain, for instance x along [0 1] and t along [0 1] with k constant to a given polynomial order.